# getting the count value in PHP using value command

Tags: php, html

I am making a dashboard using php and displaying it on webpage using html. For this I am taking some count values. Is !$value[" variable"] valid in php? How do i get the not of (!=) value? There is no other way to get the data. I am getting the values from a database.

```
print "<td><a href=\"$strBase and status!='Closed'\" target=\"_blank\">".$value[" ? "]."</td>";
```

I need to print !closed. Somehow I do not know how to pass that inside $value[].

Comment: include the code you are working on

Comment: Please add our Code , question seems not clear

Comment: I am not sure about the validity of this part: `<a href=\"$strBase and status!='Closed'\" `

Comment: Of this part neither: `target=\"_blank\">".$value[" ? "]."</td>`

Comment: why you are not manipulate condition outside of the code and use only variable.

Comment: I cannot put the code here as it is sensitive. <a href=\"$strBase and status!='Closed'\" is in html which makes the count value as a hyperlink and takes it to another page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable as a key in order to retrieve a value from an array you can do as follows (I use a snippet of your code):

```
.$value[$myVar].
```

Where `$myVar` should be a string with the name of the key you want to retreive from `$value`

But anyhow, your question is pretty unclear so I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the variable is [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), i.e.:

```
if(empty($value["variable"])){
echo "variable is empty";
}
```